# Prove that given a right triangle $T$ in the plane, reflecting it about a line $l$ results in a right triangle congruent to $T$

Tags: geometry

> Prove that given a right triangle $T$ in the plane, reflecting it about a line $l$ results in a right triangle congruent to $T$.

It is easy for me to see this by just drawing out examples, but is there a more clever way to see why this is true? My approach would be to use coordinates but that would get very difficult as finding reflections with respect to arbitrary lines is not always easy.

Comment: Reflections preserve both lengths and angles.

Comment: Is there a proof of that?

Comment: There are several ways to prove this depending on what you’re allowed to use. [Here](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa08/Eckstein/Math7210final/MATH7210FINAL.html) are a couple.

Comment: Is $l$ also in the plane?

Comment: @PhillipHamilton I’ve been assuming so, although the proposition of course holds even if it isn’t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to show that reflection preserves lengths of line segments. It immediately follows by SSS congruency that *any* triangle is congruent to its reflection.

*Geometric Proof:*
Define the reflection $P'$ of a point $P$ in the line $l$ as follows: If $P$ is on $l$, then it is its own reflection, otherwise it is the point such that $l$ is the perpendicular bisector of the line segment $\overline{PP'}$. Now, consider an arbitrary line segment $\overline{AB}$. If $\overline{AB} \parallel l$, then $ABB'A'$ is a rectangle, so $\overline{AB} \cong \overline{A'B'}$. Otherwise, extend the line segment to intersect $l$ at $C$ and let $D$ be the midpoint of $\overline{AA'}$. Then, $\triangle{ACD}\cong \triangle{A'CD}$. Similarly, letting $E$ be the midpoint of $\overline{BB'}$, $\triangle{BCE}\cong\triangle{B'CE}$, so $\overline{AB}\cong\overline{A'B'}$.

*Analytic Proof:*
Assuming that we’ve already proven that translations and rotations of the plane are isometries, we can wlog take $l$ to be the $y$-axis. The reflection of a point $(x,y)$ is then just $(-x,y)$, and since $(-x)^2=x^2$, it’s clear that the distance between any pair of points is equal to the distance between their reflections.

One could instead work out the transformation that represents reflection in an arbitrary line directly from the definition. For a line given by $y=mx+b$, the transformation turns out to be: $$
x' = {(1-m^2)x + 2my - 2bm \over 1+m^2} \\
y' = {2mx - (1-m^2)y + 2b \over 1+m^2 }.
$$ You can then grind through the algebra to show that $\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2=\Delta x'^2+\Delta y'^2$ (and also cover the case of lines parallel to the $y$-axis separately), but I find the former approach less tedious and error-prone, even if I do have to go back and prove that those other transformations are also isometries.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody says that you should reflect with respect to arbitrary lines, just perform some preliminary moves in order to make your problem more comfortable.

Remember that rotations and translations change nor angles, neither distances (this is why they are called Euclidean transformations). Therefore, by a translation you may move your figure in such a way that $l$ should pass through the origin. Next, a rotation of your plane around the origin will make $l$ horizontal. This means that after a translation and a rotation $l$ has become the $x$ axis. Then, reflection with respect to $l$ is extremely easy: you send every point $(x,y)$ into $(x, -y)$. Now you should be able to find your way by working in coordinates.